# Cron job stop working after mount operation

Tags: linux, cron, mount

I got a simple cron job which simply prints the current date to a log file. For testing purposes, I've done this cron job to occur every minute.

```
crontab -u user01 -e

* * * * * echo "Date is $(date)" >> /home/user01/date.log
```

It was used to work before I created a logical volume, give ext4 format to this logical volume and mount it to `/home/user01`. After the mount operation, it doesn't do anything.

After this, I create a crontab with just (`crontab -e`), which means I dont give the username , and the crontab started to work again. But I want to know why my first crontab not working after mount.

Also, I know the `/home/date.log` will be deleted after mount operation but the crontab should write an output to date.log every minute .

For the record, there isn't any problem with mounting. I check /etc/fstab, and df -hT. The /home/user01 directory is mounted.
Also I have tried exact same cron job for another user(user02) in another directory, and it worked so there isn't any syntax or privilige issue.

Also when I check the /var/log/cron, below output come every minute

```
(user01) CMD (echo "Today is $(date)" >> /home/user01/date.log)

(user02) CMD (echo "Today is $(date)" >> /home/user02/date.log)
```

This output comes to log file every minute so that I guess the crontab is working but not giving the output for user01 or something.

Thank you for your help

Comment: The dots are * in crontab btw :D

Comment: What are the permissions on the mounted /home/user01 directory? (Show us the result of `ls -ld /home/user01`)

Comment: That directory has drwxr-xr-x permissions. I have tried with 777 also

Answer (score 0):

You can login user01 to execute `echo "Date is $(date)" >> /home/user01/date.log`. success?

Comment: What do you mean by that? I can login to user01 and I can successfully write the  echo "Date is $(date)" >> /home/user01/date.log to a script and manually execute that so that I create the log file. But when I give that to crontab, that doesnt work